# How to change the styling of all instances of a string/symbol?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there some way by which I can change the color of all instances of string or symbol in my case * to red by html or javascript?

Comment: Yes, there are many ways to accomplish this. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Please post examples of the HTML you have and what you would like it to look like. We need more that just "all instances" and you need to show us what you tried already and what didn't work for you. On another note - we are an English only site (we will launch a Portuguese Stack Overflow sometime next year).

Comment: Strings don't have styles, elements do! You need to explain this a lot better.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
$(document.body).html(function(i,val){
    return val.replace(/\*/g,'<span style="color:red;">*</span>');
});
```

Of course it may break your html syntax.

Comment: fixed, why for regex? it supposed to replace all, so regex is ok.

Comment: @Oded explain yourself please. `replace('*',...)` would replace only first occurence.

Comment: Regex to parse/replace HTML? Shudder. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1583

Comment: like I wouldn't say that in answer... but `*` is not used in html that much.

Comment: Thing is, you can't count on that. Embedded JS multiline comments? Embedded CSS selectors?

Comment: Thats why I put the note at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
```

Depois adicione esse script(After add this script):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("[tag]:contains('*')").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("*", "<span style='color:red'>*</span>"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Substitua [tag] pela tag na qual fica o caractere, por exemplo (Replace [tag] for the tag where * is inside, for example):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("p:contains('*')").each(function () {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("*", "<span style='color:red'>*</span>"));
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to change the `*` only, then there are many ways to do that!

```
<div>Some text * Some</div>
```

Write the jQuery function as:

```
$("button").click(function () { // on a button click
   $("div").html($("div").text().replace("*", "<span class='color'>*</span>"));
});
```

After adding the span to it, use CSS to change the color:

```
.color {
  color: someval;
}
```

Phew! I finally came up with a fiddle that works! :D hehehe here it is, http://jsfiddle.net/afzaal_ahmad_zeeshan/PtpGM/1/

Comment: Does nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/EXB4d/

Comment: Sorry about that @j08691, now have a look :)

Comment: Doesn't work if there's more than one asterisk: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/PtpGM/2/

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="header">
<p>My text...</p>
<p>My text...</p>
<p>My text...</p>
<p>My text...</p>
<b>My text...</b>
```

```
<div class="body">
<p>My text...</p>
```

```
<div class="footer">
<p>My text...</p>
<p>My text...</p>
<p>My text...</p>
```

```
<!-- IMPORT JQUERY LIBRAY -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"
```

type="text/javascript">

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(e) {


//CHANGE COLOR FOR RED OF ALL P
 $("p").css("color","red");  
//Function css aplly rules css in all document our especific node
 $(".body p").css("color","black");
$(".body p").css("background","#ccc");
//CHANGE COLOR FOR BLUE OF ALL P IN FOOTER
// .dontforindentificymyclass

    $(".footer p").css("color","blue");
 });
```